# @testing-library/react `await waitFor` Failing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a custom react hook.
At any given point in time, the `Funnel` component displays only one child (a `Funnel.Step` component). It first displays the first `Funnel.Step` component (`<div>Step 1 UI</div>`).

I used `act` to change the `Funnel.Step` component. To wait for it to re-render first, I used `await waitFor` for my assertions. This makes the test fail. However, when I just do `waitFor`, the test succeeds.

This to me is confusing because the fact that the assertions passed when doing `waitFor` means that the update (`<div>Step 1 UI</div>` unmounts and `<div>Step 2 UI</div>` mounts) did indeed apply. So why does `await waitFor` fail the test?

PS: the reason I wanted to do `await waitFor` was to be able to print the changed screen (`console.log(screen.debug(undefined, Infinity))`).

```
describe("useFunnel hook", () => {
  it("should successfully render the second step in the funnel", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFunnel(["step1", "step2"]));
    const [Funnel, changeStep] = result.current;

    const { getByText, queryByText } = render(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Funnel>
          <Funnel.Step name="step1">Step 1 UI</Funnel.Step>
          <Funnel.Step name="step2">Step 2 UI</Funnel.Step>
        </Funnel>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

    act(() => {
      changeStep("step2");
    });

    waitFor(() => { // `await waitFor` fails
      expect(getByText("Step 2 UI")).toBeDefined();
      expect(queryByText("Step 1 UI")).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```

```
import { Children, ReactNode, isValidElement, useState } from "react";

export default function useFunnel<S extends string>(steps: [S, ...S[]]) {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState<S>(steps[0]);

  const changeStep = (step: S) => {
    setCurrentStep(step);
  };

  function Step({ children }: { name: S; children: ReactNode }) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  function Funnel({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    const targetStep = Children.toArray(children).find((child) => {
      if (!isValidElement(child) || child.type !== Step) {
        throw new Error(
          `${
            isValidElement(child) ? child.type : child
          } is not a <Funnel.Step> component. All component children of <Funnel> must be a <Funnel.Step>.`
        );
      }
      return child.props.name === currentStep;
    });

    return <>{targetStep}</>;
  }

  const FunnelComponent = Object.assign(Funnel, { Step });

  return [FunnelComponent, changeStep] as const;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what timing issue you may be encountering without seeing the implementation details of `changeStep`, but more than likely, you should be able await the call to `act` and skip using a `waitFor` around your expectations entirely.

Comment: When you say "await the call to `act`", what do you mean exactly? `act` doesn't return a promise.
Also, I've added the code for `useFunnel`.

Comment: My fault, I was under the assumption there was something async happening in the state update. I think the actual problem might be that you've inlined the hook call inside renderHook. My guess is waitFor is causing renderHook to create an entirely new instance of your hook which would default it back to the first step and lose the state update you made inside act. Try factoring the hook out to a const outside renderHook and see if you get the result you expect

Comment: Hooks can only be called inside a function component. So, I just didn't use `renderHook` at all and instead instantiated a test component and used `render`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the issue was

> waitFor is causing renderHook to create an entirely new instance of
> your hook which would default it back to the first step and lose the
> state update you made inside act

or something else. But the assertions were passing when the screen was showing it shouldn't.

So, I just instantiated a component that uses the `useFunnel` hook and then used `render` to render that component instead of doing `renderHook()() => useFunnel(["step1", "step2"])`. The screen now successfully shows the updated UI to Step 2.

```
function TestComponent() {
  const [Funnel, changeStep] = useFunnel(["step1", "step2"]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Funnel>
        <Funnel.Step name="step1">Step 1 UI</Funnel.Step>
        <Funnel.Step name="step2">Step 2 UI</Funnel.Step>
      </Funnel>
      <button onClick={() => changeStep("step2")}>Next Step</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

describe("useFunnel hook", () => {
  it("should successfully unmount the first step and render the second step in the funnel", async () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = render(<TestComponent />);

    fireEvent.click(getByText("Next Step"));

    expect(getByText("Step 2 UI")).toBeDefined();
    expect(queryByText("Step 1 UI")).toBeNull();
  });
});
```